# Model Objects as DataContract Object too?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I have a model obj of type business that has several props, this obj is use mainly for my dataaccess using EF with all the annotations for my validation and stuff.

now my question is, is there a guidelines on how to correctly use the same model object as a datacontract object for my wcf-related operations. i.e. if i use the same model object it will look something like this one.

```
[DataContract]
public class Business
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

anyone had any thoughts on this on what the best way or even not to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it if you use Entity Framework 4.1 Code First Or [POCO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/05/21/poco-in-the-entity-framework-part-1-the-experience.aspx). In that case the entities are not auto generated and you will not face the problem of refreshing the entities.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is not the best Idea.

Partial classes are not allowed with WCF DataContracts, so if you were to add the required annotations of a DataContract every time you refreshed your schema the annotations would disappear.

Best Practices of Web Services is to make the DataContract as slim as possible. Its Best to only send the data absolutely necessary. I would recommend making new objects and mapping the EF objects to the newly created slim objects.